# maya python iterate each obj in a list

Tags: list, loops, maya

IHello everyone I need help to understand how to access to each single object in list, if you have time...

I have a list 'objects' made by getting the user selection, I loop it to randomise position but even if seems that I properly select all the single objects, the random value is applied like they are just 1 object, everything moves together ...I'd like to random the single obj separately.
Thanks in advance
F

```
    for j in objects:
    mc.select(j)
    print(j)
    
    for i in j:
        x = random.uniform(-1,15)
        y = random.uniform(0, 12)
        z = random.uniform(-5, 15)
        mc.move(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Are your `for` loops nested? The second for loop should happen inside the first one.

Comment: yes I have the loop nested but nothing changes, I'm able to select each single obj but seems that I cant apply the random to each single obj but always as a whole...
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need the second loop for, but it seems to work fine. I simplified it a little bit like this:

```
import random
import maya.cmds as cmds
objects = cmds.ls(sl=True)
for j in objects:

    x = random.uniform(-1,15)
    y = random.uniform(0, 12)
    z = random.uniform(-5, 15)
    cmds.move(x, y, z, j)
```

Comment: yes is the same if I nest another loop actually, was just a try to go deeper....

btw if you add random rotate and scale you'll notice what the problem is, is not clear actually with only the move.

   `x_rot = random.uniform(0, 15)
    y_rot = random.uniform(0, 360)
    z_rot = random.uniform(0, 15)
    mc.rotate(x_rot, y_rot, z_rot)
    
    scaling = random.uniform(0.3, 2.8)
    mc.scale(scaling, scaling, scaling)
`

Comment: You need to pass an object to the command. Otherwise, the default behaviour is to apply the command on the current selection. Instead of `mc.scale(scaling, scaling, scaling)` you need to do `mc.scale(scaling, scaling, scaling, obj)`

Comment: thanks Morten, but I dont need to define the 'obj' somehow?

Comment: addint 'i' instead of 'obj' does the trick! Thanks for suggestion Morten ;)